# Is it possible to provide setting in app to let user turn on or off Braze notification?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on using Braze to push notification to our app. Is it possible to add a setting in my app to turn on or off push notification? If yes, how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't add notification settings in your app . but you can check notification permission status . by using this code

```
let current = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

current.getNotificationSettings(completionHandler: { (settings) in
    if settings.authorizationStatus == .notDetermined {
        // Notification permission has not been asked yet, go for it!
    }

    if settings.authorizationStatus == .denied {
        // Notification permission was previously denied, go to settings & privacy to re-enable
    }

    if settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized {
        // Notification permission was already granted
    }
})
```

if auth status is denied or undetermined then you can redirect user to your application settings to on notification by using any control (button , switch) . using this code :

```
    guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) else {
            return
        }

        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, completionHandler: { (success)
 in
                print("Settings opened: \(success)
") // Prints true
            })
        }
```

Comment: I don't want to redirect to application setting. if the notification in Notification Center is enabled. turn off in application setting will stop receive notification; if the notification in Notification Center is disabled, turn on in application setting will jump to notification setting center.